# Copy content of expired domain

Tags: seo, google-search, duplicate-content

Are there problems with using copied content from an expired domain which was crawled by Google, but now that domain is closed (website is closed by owner)?

I want to use that content on my new website.

Will there be problems with duplicate content?

Comment: Do you have permission from the owner of the closed site to use their content?   If not then duplicate content penalties are probably less of a concern than copyright infringement.

Comment: Yes, I have permission, my question is related to the impact google search, will google down my website?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not a lawyer, but as far as I know from a legal standpoint there is no difference between that and copying content from an active site, since the author of the content owns the copyright and retains it even if the site is closed or the content is not published anywhere.

Using an analogy, you can't copy a book and publish it yourself just because it's out of print, the author and their heir would retain the copyright until it expires based on the applicable laws.

If you want to use content from another site either it should be released to the public domain by the author, or that content need to be published under a license that allows other people using it without requesting express permission from the author, like the ones offered by [Creative Commons](https://creativecommons.org/) (note that this licenses usually have restrictions and/or conditions, like using the content without making any changes or using proper attribution of the author).

Comment: How about if they did have permission to copy the, how would search engines treat it?

Comment: what about the impact Google search, will google down my website by google if their bot found it is duplicate content

Answer (score 0):

Remove content from index, then it will not be duplicate. If you have permission from owner, may be you can ask for access to search console? Another way, since domain expired, you can remove content from google as outdated content (https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/6349986?hl=en)
And other option, since domain expired - you can buy it :)